# Integrate grails cloud-foundry with my grails app

Tags: grails

I am trying to integrate grails cloud-foundry plugin with my app. I am following the "One step deployment with Grails and cloud-foundry" document.

http://blog.springsource.com/2011/04/12/one-step-deployment-with-grails-and-cloud-foundry/

But my app is throwing lots of error and a warning at startup....

WARNING: Specified dependency definition compile(":cloud-support:[1.0.7,)") is invalid! Skipping..

Can anyone help me out with this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the above mentioned warning:
After installing the cloud-foundry plugin:

1. Open the dependencies.groovy file and change compile(":cloud-support:[1.0.7,)") to compile ':cloud-support:1.0.8'.
2. Change the same in plugin.xml version=[1.0.7,)" to version='[1.0.8]'.

   Now run grails cf-info.. No warning will populate.

Comment: Thanx lucky it actually worked. Though I have to make changes in some other file as well for other errors but my app is now integrated. This issue was not letting me proceed further

Comment: I actually only changed dependencies.groovy . Then it worked for me.

Comment: Actually you are right anders. Making changes in dependencies.groovy is enough but still I preferred to change the plugin.xml as well so that it doesn't create any issues in future.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the latest version of the plugin is 1.0.8, try updating to that

http://grails.org/plugin/cloud-support

Comment: Tomas: After upgrading to 1.0.8 I am still getting the same warning.... WARNING: Specified dependency definition compile(":cloud-support:[1.0.7,)") is invalid! Skipping..  But I am not getting the error any more... I am able to execute grails cf-info command... but when I do grails prod cf-push ... I get a new error ...Generating plugin.xml for inline plugin at location file [E:\grails-work\myAppName\{}]

Error: Cannot get property 'file' on null object... Now what is this

Answer (score 1):

I was able to deploy it with the help of this tutorial:
http://www.icodeya.com/2012/05/deploying-grails-apps-on-cloudfoundry.html

I installed the plugin and configured some things in the buildconfig.groovy.
That one step deployment is rather misleading.