# Specified dependency definition compile is invalid

Tags: grails, spring-mvc, cloud-foundry

"Specified dependency definition compile cloud-support 1.0.9 is invalid."  Is the error I get trying to integrate STS with the hosting service.  Just like this person, it originally installed with the wrong version of 1.0.7, and now were on 1.0.9 instead of 1.0.8; I changed it in the two files mentioned here:

[Integrate grails cloud-foundry with my grails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907513/integrate-grails-cloud-foundry-with-my-grails-app)

I also installed them in the correct order, with support going first, then foundry.  But still seeing the same error.  Even simply typing "grails clean" produces the error.  The plugin manager is correctly aware of the versions

foundry 1.2.1 / support 1.0.9

and I am aware of this link too: http://www.icodeya.com/2012/05/deploying-grails-apps-on-cloudfoundry.html  It does not have the answer.

Comment: what is the grails version? and how did you install the plugin? grails install-plugin or changing the config file? if it is the latter, can you share the piece of code?

Comment: grails version 1.3.7; both support and foundry were installed via command line

Comment: OK so I closed out the STS IDE, and re-opened.  Then tried command line clean / compiling.  Same error, but this time, it managed to get through and finish compiling.  So the show stopper became an annoyance.

Comment: if the issue is still not solved, here is what I tried out with no errors. create-app appname -> grails install-plugin cloud-foundry -> change dependencies.groovy and plugin.xml to [1.0.8,). please try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to install the plugin successfully, create-app appname -> grails install-plugin cloud-foundry -> change dependencies.groovy and plugin.xml to [1.0.8,). please try it out.